# How to set border length explicitly, using inline style within an PHP echo statement?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to set the border length of all my echo statements so that they are the same length. Right now they are reaching the end of the screen which I do not want. I am doing this within an echo statement using an inline style for each statement. Thanks

Code:

```
        echo "<p><b>Your feedback request has been added into our system!</b></p>";
        echo "<p><b>Your feedback request is as follows:</b></p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Forename:</u></b> $forename  <b><u>Surname:</u></b> $surname</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Postal Address:</u></b> $postalAddress</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Landline Tel No:</u></b> $landLineTelNo</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Mobile Tel No:</u></b> $mobileTelNo</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Email:</u></b> $email</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Send Method:</u></b> $sendMethod</p>";
        echo "<p style='border: 3px green ridge;'><b><u>Category of Info:</u></b> $catID</p>";
        // header('FeedbackRequest.html');
        // exit;
      }
```

Comment: try using table ?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: go try using table first then post what have you tried

Comment: Side note: Don't echo HTML

Comment: how else should I style echo statements then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline styles: add `width` to each definition should do it ~ thoough using a variable makes this much quicker to alter as you change it once... kinda like css '-)

```
    $style='border: 3px green ridge; display:inline-block; width:100%';
    /* an alternative */
    # $style='border:3px green inset; display:block; width:calc( calc( 100% - 6px ) - 1rem ); float:none; padding:0.5rem; margin: 1rem auto;';

    echo "<p><b>Your feedback request has been added into our system!</b></p>";
    echo "<p><b>Your feedback request is as follows:</b></p>";

    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Forename:</u></b> $forename  <b><u>Surname:</u></b> $surname</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Postal Address:</u></b> $postalAddress</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Landline Tel No:</u></b> $landLineTelNo</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Mobile Tel No:</u></b> $mobileTelNo</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Email:</u></b> $email</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Send Method:</u></b> $sendMethod</p>";
    echo "<p style='{$style}'><b><u>Category of Info:</u></b> $catID</p>";
```

Comment: incidentally I'm not sure there is a border property `ridge`

Comment: I got it from here, [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp), not sure if it is legit. Thanks for the variable tip thats a huge time saver.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
div > p {
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
sasasasasasa
</p>
<p>
sasssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</p>
<p>
sasasas
</p>
</div>
```

Try this out!